# SQL Server insert number with commas

Tags: sql-server, insert, number-formatting

I created a database table:

[image]

I run this query

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Stats (Date_of_Record, Rack_Code, Total_MB, Schools_MB, Percent_Schools, Central_MB, Percent_Central)
VALUES (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), '78Q425', 45, 297, 1, 361, 0, 12, 0)
```

and I get an error

> Msg 110, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

However, this works, but why should I NOT insert number with commas?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Stats (Date_of_Record, Rack_Code, Total_MB, Schools_MB, Percent_Schools, Central_MB, Percent_Central)
VALUES (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), '78Q425', 45297, 1361, 0, 12, 0)
```

Comment: It seems that you will have to use `REPLACE()` to turn commas into decimal points.

Comment: You asked, "why should I NOT insert number with commas?" Comma is formatting on a numeric field, you don't insert formatting into the database.  comma doesn't control precision, scale or value.  it simply formats the number for readability; which the system interprets to mean another field.  Long of it: don't use display formatting when inserting values  (do you really want to store a phone number with the input mask or apply the mask on display?) same issue here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commas delimit values. By using commas, you are telling SQL Server to expect more columns of data. SQL Server is not white space sensitive, so white space is not used as a delimiter.